# Guide axis with n.dodge duplicates axis break labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to have non-overlapping axis labels, without rotating them.

### What I tried

Recent versions of ggplot2 include `guide_axis` which seems to avoid overlapping labels based on their online documentation. However, the combination of `breaks` and a `guide_axis` with `n.dodge = 2` seems to duplicate the labels, without removing overlapping ones.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

data <- data.frame(
  x = c(1.937, 1.000, 1.937, 2.875, 2.875, 2.000, 2.875, 3.750, 3.750, 3.000, 3.750, 4.500, 4.500, 4.000, 4.500, 5.0000),
  y = c(0.759462, 0.759462, 0.759462, 0.759462, 0.733633, 0.733633, 0.733633, 0.733633, 0.650203, 0.650203, 0.650203, 0.650203, 0.500767, 0.5007679, 0.5007679, 0.5007679),
  xend = c(1.00, 1.00, 2.87, 2.87, 2.00, 2.00, 3.75, 3.75, 3.00, 3.00, 4.50, 4.50, 4.00, 4.00, 5.00, 5.000),
  yend = c(0.759462, 0.000000, 0.759462, 0.733633, 0.733633, 0.000000, 0.733633, 0.650203, 0.650203, 0.000000, 0.650203, 0.500767, 0.500767, 0.0000000, 0.5007679, 0.0000000)
)

vertical <- filter(data, y == yend)

ggplot() + 
  geom_segment(data = data, mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend)) +
  coord_flip() + 
  scale_y_reverse(
    breaks = vertical$y,
    labels = function(y) format(y, digits = 1),
    guide = guide_axis(n.dodge = 2)
  ) +
  theme(
    text = element_text(size = 16)
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-06-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: It's because your `vertical$y` contains duplicates. The problem should be fixed if you'd use `breaks = unique(vertical$y)` in your scale. You might have to manually remove either `0.5007670` or `0.5007679` though.

Comment: @teunbrand ah, thank you. That works.